# Why to do parentheses change the results of a calculation?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, physicalconstants-package

I'm getting results that are sensitive to where I place parentheses with respect to operations that are associative<sup>1</sup> (and should thus be insensitive to such placement). For example, if I define<sup>2</sup>

```
<< Units`; << PhysicalConstants`;
stellarDayTextbook = 1/(1/Day + 1/Convert[SiderealYear, Day])
```

and then calculate

```
1/stellarDayTextbook - 1/Day - 1/Convert[SiderealYear, Day]
```

I get precisely zero, as expected. But if I add parentheses

```
(1/stellarDayTextbook - 1/Day) - 1/Convert[SiderealYear, Day]
```

I get

```
-(3.03577*10^-17/Day)
```

What's causing this?

---

<sup>1. Remember, this isn't C, it's math: "subtraction" of $x$  is just the addition of $-x$. Check `TreeForm`.</sup>

<sup>2. I realize this isn't the definition of a "stellar day", but merely a textbook approximation. The distinction is not material to the question.</sup>

Comment: Subtraction is associative? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property

Comment: @alancalvitti: Ok, ok: go ahead and replace all the `-` with `+-`.

Comment: Just numerical roundoff error here. We know the order of evaluation for the parenthesized version, and clearly the order is different for the unparenthesized version. Use `Chop` on the result to get rid of the error.

Comment: Sounds to me like @murray pretty much said it; it's just one of the vagaries of inexact arithmetic.

Comment: @alancalvitti It is left-associative, which is what the OP did here.

Comment: @rm-rf: In fact, it's implemented (as my per my comment above) as addition. Try `TreeForm[x - y - z]`.

Comment: In any case, floating point operations are not necessarily associative/distributive, even if the underlying mathematical operations are.

Comment: @rm-rf: Yes, good point, as this demonstrates (and that would be a good answer).

Comment: I'm not near an mma installation now, but I'll write an answer a little later.

Comment: Actually just like in C, addition of floating point (inexact) numbers isn't associative in Mathematica either ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: Right, the calculation certainly isn't. The parsing of the expression is (unlike some programming languages and calculators).

Comment: FWIW, one aspect of this that surprises me is that the symbolic information provided in the definition of `stellarDayTextbook` was not consulted. I'd always assumed (I have no idea why) that Mathematica, in addition to performing the numeric calculation, also "checked" what symbolic information it had to see if a purely symbolic manipulation could be used to produce a different result. Here it would have shown that the expression in question was just a rearrangement of the definition of `stellarDayTextbook`, and produced `0`.

Comment: @rm-rf: Thx. I also have a [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14526/37).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ah, I think I understand now.  Do you mean that since if `a, b, c` don't have values then `(a-c) - b` and `a - c - b` evaluate to the same, we should get the same result regardless of parentheses even if we give them values? This raises some interesting questions about the actual evaluation order.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Essentially, yes, though maybe "could" instead of "should". Since Mathematica has that information (about the structure of the relevant expressions) around, it might have used it either (1) to have calculated both $(a-c)-b$ and $a-c-b$ to see if it got different results or (2) to have used its symbolic knowledge of the fact that (essentially) $a=b+c$ to conclude that either expression must be 0.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `Block[{a = 3.2, b = 2.1, c = 1.1}, TracePrint[(a - c) - b]]` suggests that if `a` and `c` have values, `a - c` is evaluated *before* the associativity rule is applied (I'm not arguing for this behaviour, just noticing it).

Comment: @rm-rf "I'm not near an mma installation now, but I'll write an answer a little later." It's been a year and then some, perhaps you could make this question answered. I do not fully know what you intended to say.

Comment: @Anon Thanks :) I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're seeing here is just the impreciseness of floating point arithmetic. It is important to remember that floating point operations are not associative or distributive even if the underlying mathematical operations are. A very simple example demonstrating the lack of associativity:

```
1. + (1.*^20 - 1.*^20)
(* 1. *)

(1. + 1.*^20) - 1.*^20
(* 0. *)
```

Much has been said and written about this topic over the years, so instead of repeating, I'll just link you to a good article to read on the subject: [D. Goldberg, "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic," ACM Comput. Surv. 23, 1 (March 1991), 5-48](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/103162.103163)

Comment: As discussed in the comments above, it's interesting that *Mathematica* does not take advantage of its knowledge of expression structure to produce a more accurate result.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius  its does If one uses exact numbers. `(1 + 1*^20) - 1*^20` gives 1

Comment: @Nasser: But only because those calculations are exact, not because *Mathematica* is removing the parentheses symbolically.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius *Mathematica* is not magic. It neither knows what you intended to achieve nor can it feasibly infer that from some kind of analysis of the sum total of all system, package, and user code that it processes. Anyway, this got my upvote for an excellent reference.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Removing parentheses is "not magic" either, especially for a system that [claims to be superior](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/compare-mathematica/#hybridmethodology) to those that provide "only numerical results, often forfeiting insight" because it gives "exact, general results whenever possible".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius removing the parentheses would not be magic, I agree. To be magical it would have to be correct.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: $(a−c)−b \neq a−c−b$?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius not necessarily, when you are working with floating point values. *Mathematica* is essentially stuck between those who want floating point numbers to behave as an exact analogy to the reals, and those who insist that they are legitimate mathematical objects in their own right, with their own special rules of algebra. I think the compromises that have been made to accommodate both of these classes of users are mostly reasonable, but there are obviously limits to what can be done. The important point is to be aware of what you are really doing so as not to be surprised.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: None of the comments are about FP values (the answer addresses that). No one is asking for magic, just something approximating the claims *Mathematica* makes for itself.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius your example makes it about as difficult as it possibly could be for *Mathematica* to predict which answer you would have liked. There are ways of getting the "correct" answer, but you choose not to use them and instead insist that the system somehow divines your intent anyway. I hate to burst your bubble, but *Mathematica* has never claimed to be omniscient. Also, the issue is quintessentially related to floating point arithmetic. If you don't want to talk about that when discussing it, then I don't know what to say to you.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Ah! We're talking about Nasser's and rm -rf's examples, not mine.

Comment: Interestingly, [Wolfram Alpha gives `-1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281.+%2B+1.*%5E20%29+-+1.*%5E20) for the second calculation "based on lexical and semantic similarity in Wolfram|Alpha's computable knowledge space".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You should give it input that it can understand... `1*^20` is _Mathematica_ shorthand for `10^20` and Wolfram Alpha won't understand that. Try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281.+%2B+10.%5E20%29+-+10.%5E20).