# Is there a way to globally set when to treat a very small number as zero?

Tags: numerics, options

I [understand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6994/37) that I can use `Chop` to force a very small number to be treated as `0` and can use `PossibleZeroQ` to as a way to test whether such a number might effectively be `0`, but applying `Chop` every time a small number is close to zero in order to "make it be" zero is tedious and error prone; while `PossibleZeroQ` seems to have its own ideas about what constitutes `0`.

Are there global settings that will let me

- treat every number smaller than some specified value as
  `0`, effectively applying `Chop` automatically to all results; and
- specify how large a number `PossibleZeroQ` should recognize as `0`?

Comment: There is a system option controlling the maximum difference when treating close inexact numbers as equal.  But I can't find it now ... should be somewhere in `SystemOptions`

Comment: @Szabolcs and raxa: you're probably looking for ``Internal`$EqualTolerance``.

Comment: @rm-rf: That looks interesting. There's no help on it though, and its value (2.10721) is cryptic.

Comment: Is it perhaps deprecated?  [1](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/$EqualTolerance) [2](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/tree/browse_frm/month/2009-12/939d71f9d7a9eb32?rnum=21&_done=/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_frm/month/2009-12?&hl=bn&pli=1)

Comment: Regarding the first point: What about `$Post=Chop`?

Comment: And note that `Chop` can tale a second argument specifying the tolerance. So you might want to use something like `$Post = Chop[#, 10^-13]&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, `$Post` is a way to go here. Take as an example:

```
FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3]

(*{0., -5.55112*10^-17, 1., 1.38778*10^-17, 1.38778*10^-17}*)
```

Now lets set $Post to `Chop` with tolerance `10^-13`.

```
$Post = Chop[#, 10^-13] &;
```

This will apply the `Chop` function to every output thereafter.

```
FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3]

(*{0, 0, 1., 0, 0}*)
```

If you want to make this behavior semi-permanent, you can set `$Post` in any one of your `init.m` files. A good choice might be the one located at

```
$InstallationDirectory <> "\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Packages\\init.m"
```

If you do this and want to not `Chop` for a particular output you can always clear `$Post` or remove this from `init.m` and restart the kernel.

Comment: Andy Ross ,Does $Post = Chop[#, 10^-13] &; really take away the digits smaller than 10^-13? I find that those digits still exist by Print[MatrixForm[FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3]]];

Comment: @novice this is a very good question that I don't immediately know the answer to. I suggest posting it as a question.