# Rounding Errors in simple Range/Table output

Tags: functions, export, list-manipulation

I get strange rounding errors from MachinePrecision values from Export. From this:

```
InputForm[Range[99.9997, 100.0003, 0.0001]]
```

I get:

```
{99.9997, 99.99980000000001, 99.99990000000001, 100., 100.0001, 100.0002, 
100.0003}
```

Or (and more importantly) the same happens when I want to write the values in a file (Range and Table produce the same result):

```
Export["test.txt", Table[x, {x, 99.9997, 100.0003, 0.0001}]]
```

The file test.txt contains:

```
99.9997
99.99980000000001
99.99990000000001
100.
100.0001
100.0002
100.00030000000001
```

If I try to fix this using

```
Export["test.txt", SetPrecision[99.99980000000001, 6]]
```

I get:

```
99.9998000000000075715433922596275806427`6.
```

and finally this:

```
Export["test.txt", N[99.99980000000001, 4]]
```

gives:

```
99.99980000000001
```

It sounds like a simple task but I can't figure out an elegant solution (that is not starting to build a string for example). Can you reproduce this behaviour? I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2.0. How can I get only numbers around 100 with 4 digit precision?

Comment: `Range[999997, 1000003, 1]/10000 // N` - How it is *seen* depends on your settings of displayed precision. See your preferences/documentation.

Comment: A common question, e.g. 
[(5580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5580/121),
[(14511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14511/121),
[(65298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65298/121),
[(66477)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66477/121),
[(91420)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91420/121)

Comment: Try converting to strings before exporting: `ExportString[ToString /@ Table[x, {x, 99.9997, 100.0003, 0.0001}], "Text"]`.  Use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) before `ToString` for more control.

Comment: @ciao I understand the display part (at least a bit ;-)), but here its more important what ends up in the text file because I use it to feed another program. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the links. ToString@NumberForm[...] does the job (see answer below). I'm not sure why I would profit from ExportString, though. It works without it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Mr.Wizard for bringing me on the right track.
Here is the shortest workaround I found using NumberForm:

```
Export["test.txt",Table[ToString@NumberForm[x, 7], {x, 99.9997, 100.0003, 0.0001}]];
```

This gives:

```
99.9997
99.9998
99.9999
100.
100.0001
100.0002
100.0003
```

Or a more general solution:

```
min = 99.9997; max = 100.0003; step = 0.0001;
Export["test.txt", Table[ToString@NumberForm[x, StringLength@ToString[step, InputForm] + 1] , {x, min, max, step}]];
```

wich gives the same but determines the precision of step automatically.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was suggesting. +1 for writing it up yourself.  `ExportString` was *only* as an example to keep from having to actually write a file.  I do that by default without thinking.  Sorry for the confusion.